# split string but only when necessary

Tags: t-sql, split

I know similar questions abound on the interweb but I can't find the solution to this exact one. I have two columns Firstname and Lastname and some of the first names have middle initials in the column and some of the last names have ', suffix' in the column. I've used `LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(lastname, 0, CHARINDEX(',', lastname)))) As lastname` and `LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(FirstName, CHARINDEX(' ', FirstName) +1, 20 ))) AS FirstName` before but that returns a blank result if there is no middle initial/name or no suffix to the last name. I've tried several different combinations of this with no luck. I need a way to ignore a middle initial if there is one but still return the first name if there isn't one (based on a space) and ignore the last name suffix if there is one but still return the last name if there isn't one (based on a comma)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try a case statement. For instance:

```
case when CHARINDEX(',', lastname) <> 0
   then LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(lastname, 0, CHARINDEX(',', lastname))))
   else lastname
end As lastname
```

Similarly with your firstname expression.

Comment: The simplest answers elude me. Thanks @Ben Thul